# Is it possible to recover constraints when using Dynamic/fromDynamic in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am designing a system which needs to track tables of different types. It would be highly convenient to have one authoritative list of the tables*, and the best way to have this list would - I think - be as a list of Proxies, as at times I do need the type. I suppose HLists are an option, but even after 2 years of using Haskell a fair amount, they look unwieldy, so I was reaching for `Dynamic`.

- Actually, it would be best to have 0 lists, and just have a way to query all available instances of a particular type class at run time, but I'm not sure there's a way to do this (last I checked).

My code currently looks like this:

```
allCowProxies :: [Dynamic]
allCowProxies = [
    toDyn $ Proxy @HoboRecord
  , toDyn $ Proxy @AF.AfiFarmRecord
  , toDyn $ Proxy @DCP.DcPrediction
  , toDyn $ Proxy @DCF.DcFreshFeatures
  , toDyn $ Proxy @DCH.DcHistorical
  , toDyn $ Proxy @SA.ShActivity
  , toDyn $ Proxy @SRE.ShRumAndEating
  , toDyn $ Proxy @SX.SxRecord
  ]

allCowRecs :: [TypeRep]
allCowRecs = catMaybes $ toTypeRep <$> allCowProxies
  where
    toTypeRep d = case fromDynamic d of
      Just x -> Just $ typeRep x
      Nothing -> Nothing
```

But this yields an error:

```
    • No instance for (Typeable proxy0)
        arising from a use of ‘fromDynamic’
    • In the expression: fromDynamic d
      In the expression:
        case fromDynamic d of
          Just x -> Just $ typeRep x
          Nothing -> Nothing
      In an equation for ‘toTypeRep’:
          toTypeRep d
            = case fromDynamic d of
                Just x -> Just $ typeRep x
                Nothing -> Nothing
   |
37 |     toTypeRep d = case fromDynamic d of
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The data types should all implement `Typeable`, but if they don't, I would expect to just get `Nothing` here, instead of the compile-time error. I guess, from looking at it, that it isn't fully inferring the type and only the outer type (Proxy).

Are there any workarounds to this, or suggested alternative approaches as well would be welcome.

**Update**

While @Li-Yao Xia's answer did directly answer the question, I ended up going for an alternative solution and wanted to document that here. It is a bit more conventional but it does require `RankNTypes` enabled.

```
data CowRecTbl =
    Hobo   (Proxy HoboRecord)
  | Afi    (Proxy AF.AfiFarmRecord)
  | DcPred (Proxy DCP.DcPrediction)
  | DcFf   (Proxy DCF.DcFreshFeatures)
  | DcHist (Proxy DCH.DcHistorical)
  | ShAct  (Proxy SA.ShActivity)
  | ShRum  (Proxy SRE.ShRumAndEating)
  | SxTec  (Proxy SX.SxRecord)

allCowProxies :: [CowRecTbl]
allCowProxies = [
    Hobo   $ Proxy @HoboRecord
  , Afi    $ Proxy @AF.AfiFarmRecord
  , DcPred $ Proxy @DCP.DcPrediction
  , DcFf   $ Proxy @DCF.DcFreshFeatures
  , DcHist $ Proxy @DCH.DcHistorical
  , ShAct  $ Proxy @SA.ShActivity
  , ShRum  $ Proxy @SRE.ShRumAndEating
  , SxTec  $ Proxy @SX.SxRecord
  ]

cowRecTblApplyPx :: forall a.
  (forall r k. EntityRec r k => Proxy r -> a) -> CowRecTbl -> a
cowRecTblApplyPx f (Hobo px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (Afi px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (DcPred px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (DcFf px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (DcHist px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (ShAct px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (ShRum px) = f px
cowRecTblApplyPx f (SxTec px) = f px


allCowRecs :: [TypeRep]
allCowRecs = (cowRecTblApplyPx typeRep) <$> allCowProxies
```

With `-Werror=incomplete-patterns` enabled, all I have to do is remember to add new entries to `allCowProxies` and the type system should remind me if I forgot anything else. I may still try Carl's suggestion in the comments at some point.

Comment: Hmm, if this approach doesn't pan out, maybe I should try existential types: https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types

Comment: When you convert back from `Dynamic` to a particular type, you must choose which type you try to convert to. `Nothing` means your choice is wrong, not (as you seem to think) that it couldn't work out at runtime which type to convert to.

Comment: At run time? Do things create new instances while your program is running? If not and the instances all exist at compile time, maybe you can draw inspiration from a silly toy I put together to experiment with metaprogramming based on instances: https://gist.github.com/chowells79/1d3560bdd7edd84de8c82c87e96cfaea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a `TypeRep` (unindexed) from a `Dynamic`, there's [`dynTypeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#v:dynTypeRep)

```
dynTypeRep :: Dynamic -> TypeRep   -- TypeRep = SomeTypeRep   in the docs
```

```
allCowRecs :: [TypeRep]
allCowRecs = dynTypeRep <$> allCowProxies
```

I don't get why you need both `allCowRecs` and `allCowProxies`, they both encode the same information.

Comment: In other words, you can just define `allCowRecs = [typeRep (Proxy @HoboRecord), ...]` and avoid an extra level of `Proxy` in your types while you're at it.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that it wasn't possible to go from `TypeRep -> Proxy a` (or even `TypeRep -> Maybe (Proxy a)`, though that would be more reasonable). I actually checked that months ago as well, maybe I looked in the wrong place. But this issue came back to bite me again after adding more tables!

Comment: I ended up coming with a slighty-less-elegant-than-my-ideal solution, but, it is pretty close ... and just uses a data type and RankNTypes - updated in my question.